# User control in custom list item edit - when can I see content type of item?

Tags: content-type, user-controls, custom-list

I have a user control I'm using to edit new list items.  In my Page_Load event, I am trying to retrieve the Content Type of the new item to use in further logic.  But, I'm getting a null reference when I try to reference the content type.  Am I going about this wrong?  Here's my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SPContext context = SPContext.Current;

    SPListItem currentItem = context.ListItem;
    SPContentType currentCType = currentItem.ContentType;
    // Do some other logic
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try getting the ContentTypeId first (using currentItem["ContentTypeId"], then retrieve the ContentType from the List.ContentTypes collection.

Comment: Thanks for that idea.  Unfortunately, for some reason, the ContentTypeId that is shown on the current item is not a real ContentTypeId.  It starts with "0x00", which is not a valid ContentTypeId.  In my situation, the ContentTypeId should start with "0x0102", since it is an "Event" (according to [link]http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms452896.aspx.

Comment: Try your code in CreateChildControls, PageLoad might be too early to get the context properly, maybe?

Comment: I have tried CreateChildControls, OnPreRender, and RenderControls, and I can't see the "Event" content type.  I can't see how Sharepoint can render the "NewItem" dialog without knowing the Content Type!

Comment: Wait, is this in the New Form or the Edit Form? If it's the New Form, the item hasn't been created and thus doesn't have a content type...

Comment: It is in the New Form.  That's the problem.  Thanks, James!